# Hibernate store YearMonth in MySQL as Blob instead of text

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

A Spring Boot 2.3.0 Project is Storing Data in MySQL 8.0. (jdk 9)

A JPA Class has Java 8 YearMonth field

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Version {
    ...
    private YearMonth releaseDate;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

When I persist an instance of version, it's stored like this:
[image]

As You can see LocalDateTime gets stored as text but YearMonth as Blob. Now When I get back the entity it works fine and I do get YearMonth value.

The problem is that I cannot read it through MySQL Workbench. And I know that EclipseLink (official implementation of JPA) does persist YearMonth as Text.

How Can I store it as Text and not BLOB?

Comment: Are you using EclipseLink ?  You can write a AttributeConverter for YearMonth to save as text.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate. and with JPA 2.2, There is no need for AttributeConverter.

Comment: Why you think there is no need for AttributeConverter when  you want to save as TEXT.

Comment: Because I used to use EclipseLink in Java EE 8 and it was stored in plain text. JPA does support YearMonth out of the box, that's why it does get persisted and retreived successfully. So JPA is not at wrong here hence no need for AttributeConverter, because you use AttributeConverter for types that jpa does not support . However the implementation Hibernate store it as Binary not text, unlike EclipseLink.

Comment: _you use AttributeConverter for types that JPA does not support_ false. You can change any type you want to convert in another type which is also compatible with your database, not only when JPA doesn't support. Since you want to save as Text you can use AttributeConverter in this case. [Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/java-yearmonth-jpa-hibernate/) is a good article about it.